# htaccess: Add random string to URL

Tags: .htaccess, random, url-rewriting

I'm having a URL like this:
`http://www.foobar.com/`

If a user enters it, I want the URL to be expanded by a random string like

`http://www.foobar.com/f896c0fb0924db5dfeae58d430c2d6ca`
(*In the example a MD5 is added, but it anything else would be fine too.*)

Is it possible to do this via `.htaccess` and some clever Rewrite-rules?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it with `mod_rewrite`, but the [programmatic mode](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) (prg) needs to be defined in the server config (you can only use them then from `.htaccess`). You could come close with a long chain of predefined strings (meh) or use other pseudo-random sources. One option is to combine various `TIME` server variables like `TIME_SEC`. With repeats and without separators, it would not be easy to notice the pattern.