# URL rewrite on apache http server on windows

Tags: apache, iis, url-rewriting, append, jsessionid

I'm using Apache Module `mod_proxy_balancer` as a load balancer on windows machine to direct traffic into different ports on iis. The apache and iis is running on the same server.

I'm running some load-testing and would need unique id to be appended to the url. Is it possible to get the JsessionId from the cookie and append that to the url. If so, how?

Another option could be to generate some unique string and append that to the url?

My Apache knowledge is little limited and don't seem to get the url rewrite working.

Here is my `httpd-vhosts config` file:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:8080>
  DocumentRoot "C:/HTTPD/Apache24/htdocs"

  #ServerName www.example.com:80

  Header add Set-Cookie: "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
  <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember "http://localhost:8081" route=node110
    BalancerMember "http://localhost:8082" route=node111
    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/ stickysession=ROUTEID scolonpathdelim=On timeout=600
  ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/
  ProxyPreserveHost On

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use random or UNIQUE_ID, another option is to combine various TIME server variables like TIME_SEC.

You could also use prg which use for Calls an external program or script to process the rewriting.

please refer this below links for more detail:

[.htaccess - Add random text after url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28504055/htaccess-add-random-text-after-url)

[htaccess: Add random string to URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778226/htaccess-add-random-string-to-url/14778438)

[Apache Module mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap)